# How to insert,update and delete on currently

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to insert to multiple table, how to update one tables from it multiple tables and how to delete it multiple on currently?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to `INSERT` to multiple tables is to write multiple `INSERT` statements.  Same goes for `DELETE`.  They are single-table operations.

You can `UPDATE` one table using several other source tables with a simple `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.Name = t3.Name
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t3.OtherID = t2.OtherID
```